# BAD UDP LENGTH > IP PAYLOAD LENGTH

Tags: udp, ip, rhel7

My client program should be sending UDP datagrams, using Raw socket for IPv4 protocol.UDP server program is unable to receive UDP messages from the socket.
After checking the PCAP file, I realized that the error is due to: "[BAD UDP LENGTH 756 > IP PAYLOAD LENGTH]  Len=728". 
I suspect that Datagrams that are too large for the socket receive buffer is getting dropped completely. But where can the packet drop be is it ad the client side or server side ?Shouldn't the packet simply be fragmented if the UDP length exceeds the IP Payload Length? How to debug this issue further with respect to UDP client and Server?